# Cannot get Spring Boot + Hibernate + Firebird database to work together

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, firebird, jaybird

It seems that I cannot find decent solution to my problem. I cannot figure out how to properly configure a Spring Boot REST project and Firebird 3.0 to work together in an Eclipse environment. I use kubuntu 20.04 Focal and already preinstalled Firebird 3.0 server, and added my people.fdb file in a src/main/resources folder and gave rw permissions to all groups. I also transferred a fdb file to a firebird:firebird ownership. I'm not sure if this should be like this. I constantly get error when run:

```
2022-06-04 20:54:42.331 ERROR 6948 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details [SQLState:08006, ISC error code:335545106]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder$Type$1.createSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:539) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder.toFlatSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:304) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readStatusVector(AbstractWireOperations.java:140) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.processOperation(AbstractWireOperations.java:204) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readOperationResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:163) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version13.V13WireOperations.authReceiveResponse(V13WireOperations.java:125) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.V10Database.authReceiveResponse(V10Database.java:569) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.WireConnection.identify(WireConnection.java:335) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.performConnect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:51) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.connect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:39) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.connect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:32) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:145) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(FBManagedConnectionFactory.java:599) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBStandAloneConnectionManager.allocateConnection(FBStandAloneConnectionManager.java:65) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDataSource.getConnection(FBDataSource.java:109) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver.connect(FBDriver.java:114) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:364) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:476) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:175) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:173) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1460) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1494) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:58) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) ~[spring-orm-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) ~[spring-boot-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
    at lt.company.peopleDatabase.PeopleDatabaseApplication.main(PeopleDatabaseApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLExceptionInfo: Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details

2022-06-04 20:54:42.335  WARN 6948 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.e.j.e.i.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator     : HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata

java.sql.SQLException: Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details [SQLState:08006, ISC error code:335545106]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder$Type$1.createSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:539) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.FbExceptionBuilder.toFlatSQLException(FbExceptionBuilder.java:304) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readStatusVector(AbstractWireOperations.java:140) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.processOperation(AbstractWireOperations.java:204) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.AbstractWireOperations.readOperationResponse(AbstractWireOperations.java:163) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version13.V13WireOperations.authReceiveResponse(V13WireOperations.java:125) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.version10.V10Database.authReceiveResponse(V10Database.java:569) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.WireConnection.identify(WireConnection.java:335) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.performConnect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:51) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.connect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:39) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.gds.ng.wire.FbWireDatabaseFactory.connect(FbWireDatabaseFactory.java:32) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    at org.firebirdsql.jca.FBManagedConnection.<init>(FBManagedConnection.java:145) ~[jaybird-4.0.6.java8.jar:4.0.6.java8 (build: variant=jaybird tag=v4.0.6 date=202204271624)]
    ..............

t(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:181) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:44) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.9.Final.jar:5.6.9.Final]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBSQLExceptionInfo: Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details`
```

My pom.xml configuration:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>lt.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>PeopleDatabase</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>PeopleDatabase</name>
    <description>People personal info storage database to quickly parse info only providing id number and/or date of birth</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web-services</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.firebirdsql.jdbc/jaybird -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
           <artifactId>jaybird</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.resource/javax.resource-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.resource</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.resource-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url:jdbc:firebirdsql://localhost:3050/~/Documents/Coding/projektai/ergo/PeopleDatabase/src/main/resources/people.fdb
spring.datasource.driverClassName:org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect
spring.datasource.username:SYSDBA
spring.datasource.password:masterkey
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto:update
spring.jpa.show-sql: true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

I am able to connect to that database using isql-fb CLI tool, and perform all of the operations there, but I suspect that something might be not OK with my server itself. firebird3.0.service when trying to connect is active.

Maybe someone will have something in mind on how to correctly configure such setup? By the way, in error message, it suggests checking firebird.log file, but when running

```bash
find / -type f -iname "firebird.log"
```

gives no results.

I am beginner with this database.

Comment: What is the setting of `AuthServer` in your firebird.conf? Judging by the error, I guess it is `AuthServer = Legacy_Auth`, and your firebird.log will contain [error _"No matching plugins on server"_](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/faq.html#error-occurred-during-login-please-check-server-firebird.log-for-details-335545106). In that case the solution is to either change your server configuration to support Srp/Srp256 and add the user as a Srp user, or to add the connection property `authPlugins` with value `Legacy_Auth`.

Comment: As an aside, having your database in `src/main/resources` makes no sense. That is not a good place for a Firebird database. Resources are things that should be packaged in the application archive (JAR), and a Firebird database is not such a thing.

Comment: AuthServer and UserManager settings in firebird.conf file were commented out, but set by default to Srp. Uncommenting and restarting service gives no results. Also i transfered db file to a root  `~` of my home. Also gives same error `java.sql.SQLException: Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details [SQLState:08006, ISC error code:335545106]`

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is that your Firebrd server is configured with the insecure setting to only allow legacy authentication. This means its `firebird.conf` has setting `AuthServer = Legacy_Auth` (N.B. the default for Firebird 3.0 is `AuthServer = Srp`).

Since Jaybird 4, Jaybird - the Firebird JDBC driver - no longer uses the Legacy_Auth authentication plugin [by default](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/drivers_documentation/java/4.0.x/release_notes.html#default-authentication-plugins).

You have basically two options.

1. Configure Firebird server to use the `Srp` and/or `Srp256` authentication plugin, and make sure your user exists for the Srp user management plugin.

   To do this, in `firebird.conf`, set `AuthServer = Srp` (or `Srp, Legacy_Auth` if you still need legacy authentication), and `UserManager = Srp` (or `Srp, Legacy_UserManager` if you still need legacy authentication). In addition, you need to make sure the user exists for Srp:

   ```sql
   create or alter user <username> password '<password>' using plugin srp;
   ```
2. Configure Jaybird to use the Legacy_Auth authentication plugin by specifying connection property `authPlugins` with value `Legacy_Auth`. This is less work than the previous option, but also less secure (Legacy_Auth limits passwords to 8 characters, and doesn't support wire protocol encryption).

   You can specify this by adding the following to your application properties:

   ```
   spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.authPlugins = Legacy_Auth
   ```

Comment: When trying to set SYSDBA user to use plugin srp, following error occurs: `SQL> create or alter user SYSDBA password 'masterkey' using plugin srp;
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08001
I/O error during "open" operation for file "security.db"
-Error while trying to open file
-No such file or directory`

Comment: @Shifras That would indicate that your installation doesn't have a security database, or the security.db setting is missing from the databases.conf file. That would seem to indicate your Firebird install is either incomplete or corrupted. When you connect with isql (isql-fb), do you include localhost, or do you just use a filename?

Comment: only a filename. If i would like to inclute localhost, how would that request look like?

Comment: For ISQL: `localhost:<path of file>` instead of just `<path of file>`. I think using that will produce the same error as you get from Jaybird. If that is indeed the case, it might be better to try asking your question on https://groups.google.com/g/firebird-support

Comment: Interesting error occured when connecting through localhost: `SQL> connect 'localhost:~/people.fdb' user 'SYSDBA' password 'masterkey';
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 08006
Error occurred during login, please check server firebird.log for details
SQL> `

Comment: Yes, because when you use it without a hostname, it uses the embedded engine, which doesn't check passwords (as an aside, when connecting to localhost, you need to use an absolute path, no `~` in it), and as the other error you mentioned above indicates, it looks like your install doesn't seem to have the security database (either not configured, or it's missing).

Comment: As a random guess, try to execute `sudo dpkg-reconfigure firebird3.0-server`

Comment: Kay, i managed to get it working now by reinstalling server completely and adding `firebird` group to my user group and assigning correct file rw and ownership rights to a `.fdb` file. 
Now i face another problem when my Java server tries to connect to a server localhost:`org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' ... Invocation of init method failed; ...org.hibernate.dialect.identity.IdentityColumnSupportImpl does not support identity key generation`

Comment: @Shifras Please ask a separate question about that problem. The underlying issue is that in Hibernate 5.x and earlier, there is no support for Firebird identity columns, so you will either need to write a custom dialect, or you need to use a different way of generating IDs (e.g. sequence or table-based).